# Backbone Model: Keep Collection when saving

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a simple Backbone model that looks like this:

```
(function () {

    App.Company = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {},

        urlRoot: "/Contacts/Companies",

        initialize: function () {
            var contactPersons = this.get("ContactPersons") || [];

            this.set("ContactPersons", new App.ContactPersonCollection(contactPersons));
        }
    });

})();
```

Whenever I save the model to the server, the `ContactPersons` collection is reset to an `Array`.

Is it really necessary for me to manually turn it into a collection, after a model is saved?

**UPDATE: This works as intended -- See answer for better approach (IMHO)**

```
(function () {

    App.Company = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {},

        urlRoot: "/Contacts/Companies",

        initialize: function () {
            var contactPersons = this.get("ContactPersons") || [];

            if (_.isArray(contactPersons)) {
                this.set("ContactPersons", new App.ContactPersonCollection(contactPersons));
            }
        },

        parse: function (response) {

            if (response.ContactPersons && _.isArray(response.ContactPersons)) {
                response.ContactPersons = new App.ContactPersonCollection(response.ContactPersons);
            }

            return response;
        }
    });

})();
```

Comment: I think that with `this.set()` you just set an attribute of the current model, and I honestly don't know if a model's attribute can be a Collection,

Comment: It can, the above code works when creating a new instance of the model. But when an existing instance is saved, to collection is reverted to a vanilla `Array`.

Comment: have you checked the communcation between client on server while saving. Anything strange?

Comment: Yes, nothing strange. The `JSON` from the server is fine. The `ContactPersons` property is of course a vanilla Array, but I wanted Backbone to automatically turn that into a collection, which is what I do in the `initialize` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send data back from the server, how are you handling the response? For example if you just send back a [{},{},{}] I don't think Backbone automatically knows to treat that as a collection. Thus, it sets the `ContactPersons` attribute as what it gets, your vanilla array.

What you can do, is override your set function inside your model which will take the array of objects passed in and write to the collection as proper. See this example:

```
set: function(attributes, options) {

    if (_.has(attributes, 'ContactPersons') && this.get("ContactPersons")) {
        this.get('ContactPersons').reset(attributes.ContactPersons);
        delete attributes.ContactPersons;
    }

    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
}
```

So basically as long as your server response is properly namespaced (response.ContactPersons) then after parsing it will pass your response to the set function. The collection data is treated specially as a collection. Here, I'm just reseting the collection that already exists with the new data. All your other model attributes should continue to be passed on to the original `set()`.

**UPDATE - Growing doubt about own answer**

I haven't been able to get this question/answer out of my mind. It certainly works, but I'm becoming unconvinced that using a modified `set()` vs. just doing things in `parse()` is any better. If someone has some comments on the difference between using a modified `set()` vs. `parse()` with nested models, I'd really welcome the input.

Comment: The server sends back vanilla JSON. Can I change the response, so that Backbone will use the collection?

Comment: Doesn't my code above take a vanilla JSON and have Backbone use it as a collection ? :-) For example, if the server sends back {'ContactPersons':[{'name':'jason'},{'name':'sara'}]} it SHOULD happily throw these guys into your collections and you'll find two new models.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it does (haven't tested). You just wrote the answer as if I could change the server response, and Backbone would pick up the collection type. But I don't think that's possible. The code in the updated question does about the same thing.

Comment: I edited your code to include a check for the `ContactPersons` collection, as it doesn't exist when creating a new instance of the `Company` model.

Comment: Sure. You could check there, you could check there and create an instance if it doesn't exist. I'd probably just throw a `new Collection()` line in your model init so that you're guaranteed that the model always has that collection. I think you get the point I'm trying to make though.

Comment: Cool. Then you wouldn't have to add the `&& this.get('ContactPersons')` check in the `set()` function. You know for a fact your model already has a proper collection. Unless you anticipate doing stuff to your model where attr `ContactPersons` could change / disappear, which I don't think is what you want. :-) You can get rid of the first line and if clause in your init as well. `this.set("ContactPersons", new App.ContactPersonCollection());` should suffice.

Comment: The `parse()` solution you have is interesting though. Particularly because truth be told, I was doing exactly that up until very recently when someone told me that manipulating the attr of the model in parse() was bad form. The consensus seems to be that parse() should be mainly reserved for namespacing. That's how I came about learning about altering the `set()`. It was an "Oooh... moment for me." :-)

Comment: Interesting regarding `parse`. `set` is fired before `initialize`, that's why I check for the existence of the `ContactPersons` collection.

Comment: That is a good point. Cancel what I said about that and plus one.